# IBM Cloud infrastructure cli error - setUserMetadata is not implemented

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am following the IBM Cloud infrastructure (ibmcloud sl) cli documentation at https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/softlayer/index.html#sl_vs_create to create a new virtual server. I am using the latest version 0.7.0.

I want to read userdata from file, so I tried options -F and --userfile.

Both options give me the same error

> "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Strategy_Behavior_Standard::setUserMetadata
>   is not implemented. (HTTP 500)".

Below is the full input and output:

```
~$ ibmcloud sl vs create --hostname node --domain mydomain.com --flavor B1_4X8X100 --datacenter syd04 --os CENTOS_7_64 --billing hourly --san --network 1000 -k 1111293 -k 1111295 -k 1111119 -F /Users/user/mycluster.sh
This action will incur charges on your account. Continue?> y
name      value   
ID        55627589   
FQDN      node.mydomain.com   
created   2018-06-06T05:05:15Z   
guid      f67ced88-77dc-45f0-84df-8e5b1cca6f6c   
Failed to update the user data of virtual server instance: 55627589.
SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented: SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Strategy_Behavior_Standard::setUserMetadata is not implemented. (HTTP 500)
```

Has anyone got this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default the **ibmcloud sl** uses the SoftLayer endpoint `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1` to perform API calls, see here about this https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/softlayer/index.html#sl_init

And it seems there is an issue in the **ibmcloud sl** because the service and method that is calling doesn't exists:

> SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Strategy_Behavior_Standard::setUserMetadata

The available services and datatypes in the SoftLayer API are listed here https://softlayer.github.io/reference/softlayerapi/

As a suggestion you can try by using the CLI command provided by SoftLayer developers which is called SLCLI, you can find documentation here:

https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/vs.html

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python

Bellow are the options you can use when creating a virtual guest:

```
$slcli virtual create --help

Usage: slcli virtual create [OPTIONS]

  Order/create virtual servers.

Options:
  -H, --hostname TEXT             Host portion of the FQDN  [required]
  -D, --domain TEXT               Domain portion of the FQDN  [required]
  -c, --cpu INTEGER               Number of CPU cores (not available with
                                  flavors)
  -m, --memory INTEGER            Memory in mebibytes (not available with
                                  flavors)
  -f, --flavor TEXT               Public Virtual Server flavor key name
  -d, --datacenter TEXT           Datacenter shortname  [required]
  -o, --os TEXT                   OS install code. Tip: you can specify
                                  <OS>_LATEST
  --image TEXT                    Image ID. See: 'slcli image list' for
                                  reference
  --boot-mode TEXT                Specify the mode to boot the OS in.
                                  Supported modes are HVM and PV.
  --billing [hourly|monthly]      Billing rate  [default: hourly]
  --dedicated / --public          Create a Dedicated Virtual Server
  --host-id INTEGER               Host Id to provision a Dedicated Host
                                  Virtual Server onto
  --san                           Use SAN storage instead of local disk.
  --test                          Do not actually create the virtual server
  --export PATH                   Exports options to a template file
  -i, --postinstall TEXT          Post-install script to download
  -k, --key TEXT                  SSH keys to add to the root user (multiple
                                  occurrence permitted)
  --disk TEXT                     Disk sizes (multiple occurrence permitted)
  --private                       Forces the VS to only have access the
                                  private network
  --like TEXT                     Use the configuration from an existing VS
  -n, --network TEXT              Network port speed in Mbps
  -g, --tag TEXT                  Tags to add to the instance (multiple
                                  occurrence permitted)
  -t, --template PATH             A template file that defaults the command-
                                  line options
  -u, --userdata TEXT             User defined metadata string
  -F, --userfile PATH             Read userdata from file
  --vlan-public INTEGER           The ID of the public VLAN on which you want
                                  the virtual server placed
  --vlan-private INTEGER          The ID of the private VLAN on which you want
                                  the virtual server placed
  -S, --public-security-group TEXT
                                  Security group ID to associate with the
                                  public interface (multiple occurrence
                                  permitted)
  -s, --private-security-group TEXT
                                  Security group ID to associate with the
                                  private interface (multiple occurrence
                                  permitted)
  --wait INTEGER                  Wait until VS is finished provisioning for
                                  up to X seconds before returning
  -h, --help                      Show this message and exit.

  See 'slcli vs create-options' for valid options
```