# SoftLayer API return SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented when invoking setUserMetadata

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I met a 500 error that returned SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented.

`SoftLayer_Exception_NotImplemented: SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Strategy_Behavior_Standard::setUserMetadata is not implemented. (HTTP 500)`

It occurred when I set user metadata after invoking createObject. And this VM stayed 'Halted' status for 'Setup provision configuration'. I just waited about 30 seconds to retry. So I programmed 60 seconds suspend. Is this value OK?

Answer (score 0):

Here was reported the same error [IBM Cloud infrastructure cli error - setUserMetadata is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712645/ibm-cloud-infrastructure-cli-error-setusermetadata-is-not-implemented)

Here the an example how to the [setUserMetadata](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setUserMetadata/) using REST call:

```
POST: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vmID]/setUserMetadata

BODY:
{
    "parameters":[
        [
            "value1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I was not able to reproduce the error, I waited 50 seconds before to run the following softlayer-go example and metadata was set successful:

```go
virtualService := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)
metadata := []string{"value1"}  

result, err := virtualService.Id(11122233).SetUserMetadata(metadata)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to set user metadata:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    // If true prints the user data
    if result == true {
        udata, err := virtualService.Id(11122233).GetUserData()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("\n Unable retrieve user data:\n - %s\n", err)
            return
        }
        jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(udata, "", "     ")
        if jsonErr != nil {
            fmt.Println(jsonErr)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
```

Output:

```
[
     {
          "type": {
               "keyname": "USER_DATA",
               "name": "User Data"
          },
          "value": "value1"
     }
]
```

And following is the response I got after calling to `/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getUserMetadata`

```
root@example:~# curl -i https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getUserMetadata
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 25 Jul 2018 15:12:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

"value1"
```

I turned off the VM (Halted) and I also was able to set a new metadata, I'm not sure how you got that error.

I recommend you to set the metadata when creating the VM because it will be set while the VM is being provisioned, following is a sample in REST with [createObject](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject/) method:

```
POST: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

{
    "parameters": [{
        "hostname": "hostname01",
        "domain": "softlayer.local",        
        "datacenter": { "name": "dal10" },      
        "startCpus": 1,
        "maxMemory": 1024,
        "localDiskFlag": false,
        "blockDevices": [{
                "device": "0",
                "diskImage": { "capacity": 25   }
            }],
        "networkComponents": [{ "maxSpeed": 10 }],
        "hourlyBillingFlag": true,      
        "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "DEBIAN_LATEST",        
        "userData": [ { "value": "someUserMetadataValue" } ]        
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I used [softlayer-go](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go) for programming. And I need to update user data quickly after creating an instance. Because my OS image will fetch data from `/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Resource_Metadata/getUserMetadata.json`. So I just wait about 90 secs to set user data.

Comment: I modified my answer and provided a go example, I'm not sure how you got that error, on my case I was able to set the metadata

Comment: Thank you. I just thought that SL considered new instance was not ready to set its' metadata so returned this error.